# Ocultar resultados menos el seleccionado SELECT

Tags: php, ajax, select, modal

Buenas el otro día un compañero de aquí me ayudo a mostrar en un select las referencias que hay de un producto en un select y las disponibles y las que salían de otras referencias ocultarlas. (Esto es editando un registro)

Todo esto se está trabajando con modales.

**Con esto envio el dato al modal**

```
 <td class="otrotdfgaz" id="select2-3<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>">
   <?php
     if($res['Referencia'] == null) echo "<span>Sin asignar</span>";
     else{
     ?>
     <span><?php echo $res['Referencia']; ?></span>
    <?php  } ?>
 </td>
```

**Con esto lo recibo en el modal**

```
 $('select#select2-3 option').each(function(index, option) { 
   var ids = option.id.split('_'); 
   var optionQuery = $(option);
      if (ids.length == 2) {
      if (ids[1] == proId) { 
       optionQuery.prop('disabled', false);
       } else { 
       optionQuery.prop('disabled', true); 
      } 
     }
   });

   if(Ref == 'Sin asignar')
     $('select#select2-3').val('0').trigger('change');
       else
     $('select#select2-3').val(Ref).trigger('change');
```

Con esto cargo de la bd las referencias y también hace que muestre la seleccionada.

```
 <select id="select2-3" value="" class="form-control" name="select2-3">
    <option value="">Sin asignar</option>
 <?php
  $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM referencias WHERE estadoMaquina = 0 ");                                                              
  mysqli_set_charset("utf8");                                                                   
  while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
 ?>

 <option value="<?php echo $res['referencia']; ?>" id="<?php echo $res['id'].'_'.$res['idProducto']; ?>"><?php echo $res['referencia']; ?></option> 

 <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

La cosa esta en que ahora ya hice que al editar un pedido y añadirle una referencia a ese pedido modifico dos tablas, una la de pedido y la otra la de referencias, donde en referencias le cambio el estadoMaquina al que corresponda.

Claro en la query al solo mostrar los que tienen estadoMaquina=0 pues no me muestra la seleccionada por que no esta como 0.

Me pregunto si hay algún modo de ocultar todas las que estan en 0 pero si mostrar la seleccionada???

Gracias Saludos

Comment: Hola, Miguel. Imagino que lo suyo sería refrescar las opciones haciendo la query de nuevo pero si quieres evitar ese paso, tendrías que añadir una opción (option) manualmente al select con el identificador del producto para que, al pasar de nuevo por el código que ya tienes, te mostrara esa

Comment: Hola @JaviMollá parece una buena idea haber si la puedo hacer, una pregunta hay alguna forma de hablar contigo para explicarte algo??

Comment: hablamos por correo o hangouts: javiermollamoreno en el gmail

Comment: Nada solucionado, e tenido que eliminar esta parte por que no corresponde hacer eso, de todo modos me apunto tu mail gracias @JaviMollá

Comment: Una pregunta en javascrio como es esto?? window.location.href = "clientes.php"; pero que en lugar de que vaya a clientes.php se quede en la pagina que este?

Comment: Si cambias esa propiedad, el navegador cambia de página

Comment: pero lo que quiero que al actualizar no cambie de pagina, si no que se quede en la misma, creo que esto era algo parecido header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); pero esto es PHP

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83314/discussion-between-javi-molla-and-miguel).